# Is Android 2.2 HTTP progressive streaming = HTTP Live Streaming?

Tags: android, audio, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

The Stagefrigh media framework (Android 2.2) supports HTTP progressive streaming.
What's that means? I.e. is this an HTTP Live Streaming protocol realization?

And how to use HTTP Live Streaming on Android, I mean what's the client - web browser, MediaPlayer or just "in-SDK" realization and I have to inherit from some class?

Answer (score 22):

One big practical diffrence is that Stagefright media Framework supports mpeg3 streaming, which the old engine didn't. So you can use (shoutcast) mp3streams for example.

Here is a simple example of implementation, which streams a shoutcast URL: http://fr3.ah.fm:9000. Note that this only works on Android 2.2 and up.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SimpleMusicStream extends Activity implements
  MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
  MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

 private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
 private MediaPlayer mp = null;

 private Button play;
 private Button pause;
 private Button stop;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
  pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
  stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

  play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    play();
   }
  });

  pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    pause();
   }
  });

  stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    stop();
   }
  });
 }

 private void play() {
  Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://fr3.ah.fm:9000/");
  try {
   if (mp == null) {
    this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
   } else {
    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
   }
   mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

   mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
   mp.prepareAsync();

   Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
  } catch (Throwable t) {
   Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Stream is prepared");
  mp.start();
 }

 private void pause() {
  mp.pause();
 }

 private void stop() {
  mp.stop();

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  stop();

 }

 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  stop();
 }

 public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
  switch (what) {
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
   sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
   break;
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
   sb.append("Server Died");
   break;
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
   sb.append("Unknown");
   break;
  default:
   sb.append(" Non standard (");
   sb.append(what);
   sb.append(")");
  }
  sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
  sb.append(extra);
  Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
  return true;
 }

 public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
  Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
 }

    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Button
  android:text="Play"
  android:id="@+id/play"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Pause"
  android:id="@+id/pause"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Stop"
  android:id="@+id/stop"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Read more
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html check Asynchronous Preparation

Comment: Many Thanx for code example!   
But my question is about protocol.   
In my understanding, a Progressive Download means you are able to watch the video while the rest of the video is loading into the player and is caching into the users temporary internet files.  
I.e. Streaming means you can click anywhere in the video and jump to where you clicked, while progressive means you have to wait for the bar to be ahead of the marker to play it.   
But what is Progressive Streaming?

Comment: In other words, using Android HTTP Progressive Streaming, will I be able to click and jump to unloaded segment?

Comment: And practical question: can I use Apple file/stream segmenter to make these "segmented" files for Live Streaming (via Apache web server) on Android platform?

Comment: Anyway... Google has dropped support for H.264 in Chrome. Android 2.3 still supports it, but... who knows what's "new" in 3.0...

Comment: I tested your code without changing any letter on 2.2, 2.3.3 and 2.3.5. However it keeps getting -111 (PVMFErrRTSP500InternalServerError). Do you have any idea? Also i used the stream you provided.

Comment: I have tried the code with both API8 and API10 (2.2 and 2.3.X) and both works fine. You need to make sure that you have permission to use internet: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> Also check internet connection,  firewalls etc. Try by running directly to phone.

Comment: Guys i used this code but was unable to stream. I want to video stream my security camera

Comment: @droidgren  I have used this code and on a 2.2 emulator and it works great however when I try it on a real device 2.2.1 it will not play. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP progressive streaming is like playing media file in the mean time downloading the file.

Is not realization.
1st, stagefright doesn't contain any .m3u8 file handler.
2nd, stagefright doesn't support .ts file format.

currently, you can reimplement your mediaplayer for playing live streaming.

Comment: So, there is no real streaming. Because "playing media file in the mean time downloading the file" and "no M3U8 handler" means progressive (http) download.