# Internet Streaming Radio on an android application

Tags: android, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have an Internet Radio and to be honest I went through almost everything to get how can I actually make a Streaming android application and what i should use for that .. no use .. not a single useful information ..

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most commonly done with Shoutcast/Icecast HTTP streaming to a MediaPlayer component contained in a Service.

NPR has open-sourced their app, and it's a great reference application for radio.
http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/

Note: Shoutcast streaming is currently broken in Google TV, so your app will not work on those devices unless you choose another protocol.

If you wish to only support android 3+ (including Google TV) you can also try streaming over HLS HTTP. This protocol is much less commonly used for radio, though.

Comment: thanks man .. you really helped me .. // i found a really good and simple code too 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595491/is-android-2-2-http-progressive-streaming-http-live-streaming